# What kind of normalization is used here in database structure?

Tags: database

Hello I have a Database like three tables:

**Customer:** Customer ID, Customer Name, Customer Surname

**Product:** Product ID, Product Name, Product Price

Now I have another table

**CustomerProduct:** Customer ID, Product ID

Here are all bought stuff standing, while taking the customer id and product id.

I just ask what kind of normalization of database structure this is?

Can you give me an explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a table, which handles many-to-many relationships by storing the two related primary keys (as foreign keys) is called by various names, but [*junction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) table seems to be the standard (I personally use *association* table).

Most relational databases do not handle many-to-many relationships natively - you need an extra table like this.